# How to pass by reference so I can modify it in the calling function?

Tags: go, pass-by-reference

How can I pass something to a function such that it is modifiable and can be seen in the calling stack ? ( in other words how to pass a pointer or a reference ? )

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
)

func process(names *[]string) {
    fmt.Print("Pre process", names)
    names[1] = "modified"
}

func main() {    
    names := []string{"leto", "paul", "teg"}
    process(&names)

    fmt.Print("Post process", names)
}

Error:
invalid operation: names[0] (type *[]string does not support indexing)
```

Comment: You are passing a pointer, but you don't need one to modify an element in a slice: https://play.golang.org/p/vVSIhkcUUb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereferencing a pointer has higher precedence.
Here is a code that works: https://play.golang.org/p/9Bcw_9Uvwl

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func process(names *[]string) {
    fmt.Println("Pre process", *names)
    (*names)[1] = "modified"
}

func main() {
    names := []string{"leto", "paul", "teg"}
    process(&names)
    fmt.Println("Post process", names)
}
```